# JIRA related issues condition on epic with JQL

Tags: automation, jira, jql

I need an automation rule to set a label in JIRA if the Epic of the issue created is of a certain project.

It always fails on the latest condition. I've tried several things already;

- JQL condition {{triggeredissue.epic.project.key}} = PDJ
- JQL condtion with {{issue.epic.project.key}}
- ..

Never seem to be able to get it to work.
[image]

Tried:

- JQL condition {{triggeredissue.epic.project.key}} = PDJ
- JQL condtion with {{issue.epic.project.key}}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following matching JQL condition:

```
project = PDJ
```

As can be seen in the screenshot:
[automation rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKMU7.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34499715)